# ValueError: Number of features of the model must match the input. Model n_features is 356 and input n_features is 164

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Error is as stated above.  I think it might have something to do with my get_dummies function, but because I'm horrendously new to this I honestly am not sure.  Any help/insight for my dumb neophyte self is much appreciated.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.ensemble import BaggingClassifier
from sklearn import tree

df = pd.read_csv("D:/Machine Learning/Kaggle/Loan Prediction/train.csv")

df = df.dropna()

print(df.isnull().sum())

train, test = train_test_split(df, test_size=0.3, random_state=0)

xTrain = train.drop('Loan_Status', axis=1)
yTrain = train['Loan_Status']

xTest = test.drop('Loan_Status', axis=1)
yTest = test['Loan_Status']

xTrain = pd.get_dummies(xTrain)
xTest = pd.get_dummies(xTest)

model = BaggingClassifier(tree.DecisionTreeClassifier(random_state=1))
model.fit(xTrain,yTrain)
score = model.score(xTest,yTest)
print(score)
```

Comment: You have 2 options to correct for the error: either move `.get_dummies` above your `train_test_split`; or use vectorizers like `OHE`, `CountVectorizer`, `TfidfVectorizer` from `sklearn` and `fit_transform` them on train and `transform` on test. The reason you're getting your error is feature distributions are different in your train and test.

Answer (score 0):

One of the possible solutions to your problem is getting dummies before you split to train and test:

```
df = pd.read_csv("D:/Machine Learning/Kaggle/Loan Prediction/train.csv")

df = df.dropna()
df_X = df.drop('Loan_Status', axis=1)
df_X = pd.get_dummies(df_X)
df_y = df['Loan_Status']

train_X, test_X, train_y, test_y = train_test_split(df_X, df_y, test_size=0.3, random_state=0)

model = BaggingClassifier(tree.DecisionTreeClassifier(random_state=1))
model.fit(train_X,train_y)
score = model.score(test_X, test_y)
```